# Pass two or more values without session

Tags: jsp, servlets

How do i send two or more values from a JSP page to another JSP page or servlet without using session? I am new to JSP so suggest something pls?

Comment: What about GET params?

Comment: You can use request object instant of session. Request.setParameter("id","value"); then you can get it by getparameter("id");

Comment: suppose i have 2 jsp pages- 1.jsp and 2.jsp. Button click in 1.jsp calls 2.jsp where data from 1.jsp is stored in a db. After storing i need to call 1.jsp again and display the updated db. now how do i keep track of the row inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can not understand why you will not use session. but you have 4 another way that i know:

- use get Parameter:for example you have a link to second jsp file. add your parameter at the end of your link. like this:  `mysite.com/second.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2`
- use form in the firstjsp page and in this use hidden input:

  `<form action="second.jsp" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1" />

     <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2" />

     <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Page" />

  </form>`
- use application variable but if your data is general for all, or use speciall param name for store your value. for example you can use:

  `<%
      application.setAttribute("user1_param1","value1");
  %>`
- use RequestDispatcher in your code. and set your param in the request object instead of session.

  `<%

     request.setAttribute("param1","value1");

     RequestDispatcher r=request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp");

     r.forward(request, response);

  %>`

please Subtilize that you can use each other in the different state. for example you can use RequestDispatcher when you will forward a request before send any result ro user. and the other ways use when you will your current data back to you in the second page in the next use request.

Answer (score 0):

A session is required when you want to communicate between multiple requests. It can store data for multiple requests and identify that they come from the same client.

If you are passing directly from one jsp to another jsp then you don't even need some mechanism like session. YOu can do it with simple `request` and `response` objects. For example, if you have a form with parameters `username` and `password`,then you can access it in the servlet using

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

where `request` is `HttpServletRequest` object. 
If you want a page to forward to another page with included parameters, then you can use a dispatcher

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("someJSP.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard tag library to add all required params to the second jsp. So you basically import the library, create a variable with the desired link, and finally create a way to allow the user to execute it. It could be something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:url value="anotherPage.jsp" var="url">
  <c:param name="param1" value="${'parameter1'}"/>
  <c:param name="param2" value="${'parameter2'}"/>
</c:url>

<a href=${url}>this is my link</a>
```

EDIT:
After reading your comment i could tell you this:

**Quick answer**: If you need track of all modifications then your 1.jsp should check the data from the db, otherwise 2.jsp could send the data to 1.jsp using *c:url* or any other mechanism.

**Long Answer**: If your 2.jsp stores data directly into the db then this is not the way of doing it! you could be using a servlet instead. And this basically depends of hat kind os page are you trying to do. I see these two cases:

1. you have a page in which you have a table showing several rows

   - servlet (read data from db)
   - showAllData.jsp (shows data)
   - servlet (redirects to page)
   - insertOrUpdate.jsp
   - servlet (stores data)
   - showAllData.jsp (shows data)
2. You have a page allowing the user to edit only one record

   - update.jsp (shows no data)
   - servlet (persirst data into db)
   - update.jsp (shows updated data)

Also, take into account these tips:

1. If you want to go from a servlet to a jsp you should do something like this:

   RequestDispatcher rdispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("showAllData.jsp");
   rdispatcher.forward(request, response);
2. You could have a hidden html field in each  that you want to submit to a servlet. Inside that field you have some kind of key to identity the `operation` that you want to execute.

   <form action="MyServlet" method="GET">

   <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="READ_ALL"/>

   ...

   </form>

And

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  String operation = req.getParameter("operation");
  if ("READ_ALL") {
    readDataFromDb(req, res);
  }
  if ("INSERT_RECORD") {
    insertRecordIntoDb(req, res);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: then your link would be rewriten to something like: _anotherPage.jsp?param1=Parameter1&param2=parameter2_

Comment: yea man thanks. U gave me whole new ideas for further part of my project.

Comment: Once you master all this stuff you could consider using frameworks that do all the glue for you. For example: jsf2, struts2

Answer (score 0):

Use **query strings** or use **RequestDispatcher** for this purpose without use of sessions.